# Need a pathlist pattern to make sbt happy

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

So with one dependency I've entered a level of entanglement that I can't escape. I hate to think what will happen when I bring in the commented jars:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
//  "org.apache.avro" % "avro" % "1.8.1" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "log4j"),
//  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.10.0.0",
  "org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "1.2.2"
    excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "log4j")
    exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-api"),
  "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.16"
)
```

Using sbt assembly, I am getting the following deduplicate problem:

```
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\G517329\.ivy2\cache\org.datanucleus\datanucleus-api-jdo\jars\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:plugin.xml
[error] C:\Users\G517329\.ivy2\cache\org.datanucleus\datanucleus-core\jars\datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:plugin.xml
[error] C:\Users\G517329\.ivy2\cache\org.datanucleus\datanucleus-rdbms\jars\datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:plugin.xml
```

Where I'm stuck is trying to find a merge strategy that allows these three jars to happily coexist in one fat jar. I've tried several variations of the strategy below, but am making no progress:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "transaction", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(xs @ _*) if xs.last endsWith "plugin.xml" => MergeStrategy.discard
  // case PathList("org", "datanucleus", "datanucleus-api-jdo", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  // case PathList("org", "datanucleus", "datanucleus-rdbms", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

I must have some misunderstanding of how this works because it seems to me that the second line should find every `plugin.xml` file in every jar and nuke it.

Has anyone successfully included hive-jdbc in a fat jar?

UPDATE:

`case "plugin.xml" => MergeStrategy.discard //or .last` should work, I would think, but that throws:

`[error] (*:assembly) java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I load up the project this morning and give it one more try. This time

`case "plugin.xml" => MergeStrategy.last`

does not throw, and I have a fat jar.

Guh.

UPDATE:

I don't know where the problem lies (Intellij, SBT Console, sbt-assembly), but there is some caching going on that makes it really difficult to troubleshoot merge issues. I'm finding that the only reliable way to ensure that changes I make to the code in build.sbt are actually applied is to shut down the entire IDE and re-open it.